# Finding integral points on an elliptic $y^2-3y=x^3+x^2$ curve using the LMFDB-database

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, elliptic-curves, integers

I have the following elliptic curve that I want to look up in the [LMFDB-database](https://www.lmfdb.org/):

$$\text{k}:\space\space\space y^2-3y=x^3+x^2$$

Using the Weierstrass form of my elliptic curve, I wrote my equation in the form:

$$y^2+a_1xy+a_3y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6$$

Which gives $a_1=0,a_2=1,a_3=-3,a_4=0$ and $a_6=0$. Then I will get two parameters of this elliptic curve:

- Discriminant:
  $$\Delta=-b_2^2b_8-8b_4^3-27b_6^2+9b_2b_4b_6$$

Where $b_2=a_1^2+4a_2,b_4=2a_4+a_1a_3,b_6=a_3^2+4a_6$ and $b_8=a_1^2a_6+4a_2a_6-a_1a_3a_4+a_2a_3^2-a_4^2$.

Using my values I get:

$$\Delta=-2331$$

- j-invariant:

$$\text{j}=\frac{\left(b_2^2-24b_4\right)^3}{\Delta}$$

Using my values I get:

$$\text{j}=-\frac{4096}{2331}$$

But when I tried to [look up my elliptic curve](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/?jinv=-4096%2F2331) using the discriminant I didn't find mine.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put the sequence of Weierstrass coefficients $[a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_6]=[0,1,-3,0,0]$ into the LMFDB search engine, and it gave [the link](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/777/b/1) to the curve
$$
y^2+y=x^3+x^2+2.\qquad (*)
$$
Apparently this is the minimal Weierstrass model. If you substitute $y\mapsto y-2$ into $(*)$ you get your equation back. Anyway inverting that subsitution gives you the list of integer points on your curve
$$
(-1,3), (0,3), (9,30)
$$
and the negatives of those points.

> My very limited experience with using LMFDB suggests that typing in the Weierstrass coefficients is the simplest way. It will automatically show the minimal Weierstrass model isomorphic to the curve I input.

Comment: Your link does lead to the general website, not to a specific curve?

Comment: Sorry about that. I copy/pasted from the wrong tab. Should work now, @Joiryu.

Comment: I see. But this does not correspond to my equation, because it has different coefficients? Or am I wrong about that?

Comment: I described how I got there. Working out the transformation bringing this curve to yours is not difficult. *LMFDB search engine automatically takes you to a standard (=minimal?) model.* Try it a couple times more.

Comment: Yes I see now, thanks. Are the integral points, that are given by the database the only ones (is that proven)?

Comment: I don't know. Click the link *Reliability of the data* in top right corner for all the details. They claim that the list of integer points has been verified by other means, so I would trust it, but I'm not an expert.

Comment: And what will the curve be if I have the coefficients: [0,3,−3,0,0] because if I use the search at the website I get a errormessage? So I've the equation: $$y^2-3y=x^3+3x^2$$

Comment: When I entered [0,3,-3,0,0] I was taken to [this curve](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/135/a/1) They seem to depress the cubic polynomial on $x$ with a linear substitution and do the same to the quadratic on $y$.

Comment: Thank you very much. What substitution do I've to take to go back to my previous equation $$y^2-3y=x^3+3x^2$$?

Comment: $(y+2)^2-3(y+2)=y^2+y-2$ and $(x-1)^3+3(x-1)^2=x^3-3x+2$.

Comment: If I use that I get: $$y^2+y=x^3-3x+4$$ which is not my original equation , right?

Comment: It is exactly the variant of your curve LMFDB gave me in response to [0,3,-3,0,0]$. Use it.

Comment: Yes I will, but I've to trace it back to some original equation and therefore I need to know the substitution that is done by LMFDB. So that's why I'm aksing